# How do I close a window using a button (window.close() doesnt work)?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc

I open a new window and would like to give the user the option of closing the window using a button.  I thought window.close() would work, but nothing happens.  Below is a copy of my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function CloseWindow() {
    //window.open('', '_self', '');
    window.close();
}
</script>
....
<input type="button" value="Close Window" onclick="CloseWindow();" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.close()` only works in a window that was opened via javascript (a popup)

Comment: Thanks :), so is there another way to close the window?

Comment: Ask the user nicely to close the window themselves - they opened it. window.close() used to work for all windows, but this feature was abused, so it is no longer enabled for windows which weren't created by JavaScript.

Comment: for the user: yes (ctrl+w, alt+f4, click the close box etc.) :-) for you: no